# Tegra K1 DirectX 12 support

Tags: android, arm, directx, nvidia

everyone, I´ve searched web and since I didn´t find anything ( either I have much to learn about using google or it´s not there ) I decided to ask here.

So, can anyone explain to me what use it is that Tegra K1, which has ARM architecture, supports DirectX? I don´t think there is any way to use DirectX on Android. Unless NVidia is trying to target Windows 8 RT, I don´t see any reason to include it and make such a big deal out of it.

Comment: "DirectX 11" is being used here as a short-hand for a hardware feature set. This is not really about the "DirectX API" which is indeed Microsoft platform specific.

Comment: I'm sure Nvidia would love to see Tegra K1 used in Windows RT tablets . The Microsoft Surface 2 used Nvidia's Tegra 4 CPU so it's not out of the question. In any case, I don't see how mentioning that it has a DirectX 11 capable CPU is really making that big of a deal.

Comment: So it has some sort of instruction set of it´s own, allowing to use some of Direct3D functions on any platform?

PS: Sorry, I meant the reviewers were mentioning DirectX before OpenGL ES and generaly made it seem like some sort of breakthrough.

Answer (score 0):

[Tegra K1 Specs](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/tegra-k1-kepler-project-denver,3718.html)

only OpenGL ES 3.0 not support for DirectX 11